# Блок с описанием становится некликабельным

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется простенький скрипт:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
                $('.wrapper').hover(function(){
                    $(this).children().stop().animate({marginTop: '100%', opacity: 0}, 600)    
                },function(){
                    $(this).children().stop().animate({marginTop: '0%', opacity: 1}, 600)   
                });
            })

</script>
```

Мне нужно чтобы после того как блок wrapper уедет после наведения курсором и откроется другой блок с описанием за ним, можно было кликать на ссылки в этом другом блоке. А то в данном случае он становится некликабельным.

Comment: попробуйте так:

    `<script> $(function(){ $('.wrapper').hover(function(){ $(this).children().stop().animate({marginTop: '100%', z-index: '-1', opacity: 0}, 600) 
    },function(){ $(this).children().stop().animate({marginTop: '0%', z-index: '1', opacity: 1}, 600) 
    }); })
    
    </script>`

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению.

Comment: дайте [фиддл][1] с тем, что у вас есть: html, стили, js


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @GnidaGnideGnid, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Отформатировал.
http://jsfiddle.net/LVaYc/21/
в jsfiddle выкладывю впервые и не могу запустить работу js. может вы разберетесь.

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное.

Comment: Сделал ответом, можете принять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас там неверный код, вы этого хотите добиться: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/skL4d/ ?

P.S> Если быть откровенным jQuery там не нужен совсем: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/5MKaz/

Comment: только хотела свой вариант выложить, а он такой же..

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за упрощение. Будем учиться.)